how to determine if light-dark() css is supported officially?
Is there an official way to know if light-dark() is supported in google chrome (Version 125.0.6422.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)) besides caniuse...
According to caniuse it is supported but I cannot seem to get it to work.
(Works fine in edge)
I used the example code straight from mdn web docs


:root {
  /* this has to be set to switch between light or dark */
  color-scheme: light dark;
  --light-bg: ghostwhite;
  --light-color: darkslategray;
  --light-code: tomato;
  --dark-bg: darkslategray;
  --dark-color: ghostwhite;
  --dark-code: gold;
}

* {
  background-color: light-dark(var(--light-bg), var(--dark-bg));
  color: light-dark(var(--light-color), var(--dark-color));
}

code {
  color: light-dark(var(--light-code), var(--dark-code));
}
<h1><code>light-dark()</code> CSS function</h1>
<section>
  <h2>Automatic</h2>
  <p>This section will react to the users system or user agent setting.</p>
</section>
<section class="light">
  <h2>Light</h2>
  <p>
    This section will be light due to the <code>color-scheme: light;</code>.
  </p>
</section>
<section class="dark">
  <h2>Dark</h2>
  <p>This section will be dark due to the <code>color-scheme: dark;</code>.</p>
</section>



even tried the meta tag
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
in chrome it only displays the light version even if I have dark mode selected in settings.
(Using edge the result changes depending on light or dark mode selected)
In using the dev tools emulator it works but I believes that is because the emulator uses the @media which is what I thought light-dark() was supposed to avoid.

My chrome version is “125.0.6422.142” and it works. Can you add this @supports (color-scheme: light dark) {* {background-color: red;}} to your css for debugging and see if anything changes?

Thanks for the response @ilyasbilgihan - Yes adding @supports works, the background is red.

This passes as well - @supports (background-color: light-dark(var(--light-code), var(--dark-code))) {* {background-color: red;}}  so there must be something else going on possibly in settings.  odd.

Have you also tried incognito mode? Maybe your extensions are causing this

no difference - I disabled all extensions just to see and that didnt help.  really frustrating.  Going to look into saving all my bookmarks and probably uninstall and reinstall.  Kind of of at a loss as to what would cause it.

uninstalled (Complete - data and everything) reinstalled - no change.  Stumped for sure - one thing I did notice is that its not functioning on the sample page from mdn docs for me either.  You said it functioning for you  so I'm not exactly sure what system setting would have any control over it - that doesn't make sense to me..

Yep, the reproduced demo is not working for me in Chrome 125.0.6422.142, or Firefox 126.0.1; though the MDN demo works flawlessly in both browsers.

@DavidThomas the MDN demo, there are custom classes to force apply each color-scheme, but not here in reproduced demo. This may cause the difference but changing my system scheme also works as expected for the reproduced demo here.

even with the most basic version i.e. `:root {
color-scheme: light dark;
}
body {
background-color: light-dark(#eee, #333);
}`  It fails to render as expected based on appearance settings but works in edge.  any examples of the light-dark() function that I could find in tutorials etc all fail in chrome on multiple machines so I was thinking there was a bigger issue but Im puzzled though that it works for your browser.

The css of the example is missing the rules for .dark and .light classes to specify the color-scheme on them.

Thanks @Danny - yeah for some reason my original code was edited by someone in whatever the staging area is haha..  I used the exact code from the mdn page as my test  as well as the most basic version I listed above - after more testing the issue is with chrome not picking up the prefers-color-scheme in the media query list..  its basically returning false in all three modes selected Light , Dark, or device. so its progress but it still not solved.

So I believe I got to the bottom of it .
To get the Prefers-Color-Scheme header to change (which allows all the color CSS parts to function) in Chrome, you need to adjust the Windows settings under Personalization > Colors, not the appearance settings in the browser. It doesn't make much sense to me why they would implement it this way, but that's how it works.
In edge, it responds to the appearance setting in the browser.
two wasted days but at least I know now.

That sounds like a bug in chrome. It shouldn’t use your system’s preference for prefers-color-scheme if you have the browser set to override that theme.

you can always prefer to this website to know which browse support these functionality.
https://caniuse.com/?search=prefers-color-scheme
and it support the newer version of chrome.
may be there be a css code that already had set background color for you so try to find that code or there may be chrome flag issue.
you can also use developer tool to find out if there are any conflict.
All the best!

thanks @shubham kumar  Turns out the issue with chrome is that the Sec-Ch-Prefers-Color-Scheme: header always returns light no matter what the user has set in settings as their preference.  So even though caniuse might say its supported - that doesnt equal that it works the way its supposed to haha.  Took some digging to to see it but for anyone interested you can go here link  and look at the headers in dev tool as you change the appearance setting - try in both chrome and edge to see the difference.  Unfortunate that it doesnt function.
